# Laravel 5.8 Follower system error "No message"

Tags: php, laravel

I'm implementing a follower system for my Laravel app and I'm getting an error thrown at me when I try to hit my controller to handle the new follow. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

User Model

```
public function followers(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'followers', 'leader_id', 'follower_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function followings(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'followers', 'follower_id', 'leader_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

FollowerController

```
public function followUser($id){
        return 'Hello!';

        $user = User::find($id);

        if(!$user){
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'User does not exist.');
        }

        $user->followers()->attach(auth()->user()->id);

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'You now follow the user!');
    }

    public function unfollowUser($id){
        $user = User::find($id);

        if(!$user){
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'User does not exist.');
        }

        $user->followers()->detach(auth()->user()->id);
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'You unfollowed the user!');
    }
```

Routes

```
//Followers
Route::post('/user/{id}/follow', ['as' => 'user.follow', 'uses' => 'FollowerController@followUser']);
Route::post('/user/{id}/unfollow', ['as' => 'user.unfollow', 'uses' => 'FollowerController@unfollowUser']);
```

Follow button in view

```
 <a href="{{route('user.follow', $user->id)}}" class="userButton2 btn">Follow</a>
```

I'm quite new at this and not entirely sure what I'm doing so it is very likely that I've made a basic mistake too. Please let me know if I need to attach any further code or explanation. Thanks!

Comment: In Your routes definition, You define 'user.follow' as post request but in your view you define get request. Just change your routes post to get.

Comment: Oh dang, thank you very much! I completely missed that. One more question, would I be better off using an AJAX request for such a follow system?

Comment: It's actually up to your requirement. If You don't want to reload every time follow or unfollow someone then you need ajax request. I think in this kind of application ajax is more preferable.

Comment: Understood! Could I write an ajax get request using this same logic that I have in my controller and then define in my script how I want to manipulate the DOM? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes! you can. Just send a get request through ajax.